# Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\\InventoryReservationsApi\\Model\\GetReservationsQuantityInterface

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error, interface

I just installed the latest magento 2 (Magento-CE-2.3.2) and imported a database from another working magento 2 store with Magento 2.3.1.

But if I try to load a product in the frontend, then I get a 500 error and the message

> [Wed Jul 17 10:34:29.291844 2019] [php7:error] [pid 10517] [client
>   192.168.40.161:59517] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\InventoryReservationsApi\Model\GetReservationsQuantityInterface
>   in
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Invento...')\n#1
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Invento...')\n#2
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
>   'Magento\\Invento...', NULL, 'getReservations...',
>   'Magento\\Invento...')\n#3
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArguments
>   in
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
>   on line 50, referer:
>   http://entwicklung.hausfux.m2/produkte/insektenschutz/fenster/spannrahmen.html

What am I supposed to do? Im new to magento 2.

**Update:**

I followed the instructions from Muhammad Hasham's answer and also executed `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, now I get another error.

> [Wed Jul 17 11:29:03.970607 2019] [php7:error] [pid 10608] [client
>   192.168.40.161:63754] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not
>   exist in
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#1
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#2
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#3
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#4
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ in
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php
>   on line 19, referer:
>   http://entwicklung.hausfux.m2/produkte/insektenschutz/fenster/spannrahmen.html

Comment: Try to run composer upgrade command first.

Comment: I just tried it, makes no difference. I also cleared cache afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use redis, run:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

or you'll need to run the following commands:

- Clear `generated`
- Clear `var/cache`
- Enable Magento modules: `php bin/magento module:enable --all`
- Compile DI `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I don't use redis, but the server where I have copied the database from uses redis.

Comment: ok if you don't use redis, run the other commands which I mentioned in the answer

Comment: The folder `var/generation` does not exist, I cleared var/cache and executed the other two commands, now another error appeared. It says "update your database" so I executed `bin/magento setup:upgrade` but now I get another 500 error **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\ResourceConnection\\Proxy does not exist**

Comment: Oh you have to run di:compile and static content deploy after setup:upgrade command. Again run these commands
`php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: I tried it, now the site loads already for about 2 minutes and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you the got same error which you mentioned in the question against my name after running these commands:   `php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade`  |  `php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile`   | 
    `php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`     | `php bin/magento cache:clean`  |    `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: I got another error saying that var/cache is not writable, so I changed the owner and group everywhere to the webserver user/group which is *wwwrun* by executing `chown wwwrun:wwwrun -R *` from the root directory and now everything works :) Thx!

Comment: Glad it helped you. +1 on your question for appreciation. keep coding :) thanks :)

Comment: yup, redis it was

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the case where a dependent module was disabled. I didn't have to enable all the modules

`php bin/magento module:status`

review the modules, and only enable what you think may be the cause